# CSS Media Queries Not Working on Mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I'll keep it concise.. Using Zurb Foundation 5 to build a site. Media Queries not working. Code is as follows:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>...</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
```

Relevant CSS is set up like this:

```
    #examplediv {
    style:background-image;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { 
        #examplediv {
        style:different-background-image;
    }
    }
```

Using em in media query, per [this page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html)

Any ideas?? Going crazy here. Thanks!

Comment: What doe you mean by "not working"? How is the rule not applied in what context?

Comment: Use `(max-device-width: 40em)`

Comment: Could be CSS error - do you have actual code?

Comment: @Pekka웃 by not working, i mean it doesn't recognize any style i put in media query

Comment: @mdesdev THANK YOU! i knew it had to be something simple, just maddening i couldn't figure it out. thank you!

Comment: Have u tried use other units than em, like px?

Answer (score 10):

Using this meta tag and media query,

```
<header>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</header>




  /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 320px)
    and (max-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 321px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (max-width : 320px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 768px)
    and (max-width : 1024px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 768px)
    and (max-width : 1024px)
    and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 768px)
    and (max-width : 1024px)
    and (orientation : portrait) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 1224px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* Large screens ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 1824px) {
    /* Styles */
    }

    /* iPhone 4 ----------- */
    @media
    only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    /* Styles */
    }
```

Comment: I added the meta viewports and your answer worked just fine... thanks for this @PiyushMarvaniya

Answer (score -1):

Media Queries wont be working when you add it in Foundation.css file. You Should create a seperate CSS file for media Queries and overwrite it. Create a file and write the code as follows. I have written for changing color.

```
     @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {  
      body {
         background-color: yellow;
           }
     }

     @media only screen and (min-width: 41em) { 
      body {
         background-color: red;
           }
     }
```

Just change the tag of Background-color to image.